# Physical problem with logarithmic potential

Tags: classical-mechanics, particle-physics, potential, interactions

Could someone tell me please examples of physical situations (if there are) where there might appear a potential of the form

$$V(r)=V_{0}\ln(r/\xi),$$

being $r>0$ the radial coordinate in spherical 3D, $V_{0}$ is a constant and $\xi>0$ is a constant scale?

Comment: This post (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: dear @Qmechanic which post?

Comment: It looks like the potential inside a uniformly charged sphere with density prop. to $1/r^2$, so it diverges at the origin.

Comment: $\log(r)$-type potential are typical of cylindrical, not spherical, symmetry.

Comment: what about a mass with density 1/r^2, then the field is M/r^2=rho Vol/r^2=r^3/r^4=1/r, so the potential is ln(r)

Comment: dear @ZeroTheHero log(r) is in 2D (cylindrical =>planar symmetry), I'm asking in 3D which implies isotropic symmetry

Comment: dear @ArmandoEstebanQuito I meant at the level of interactions, not at the level of mass or charge distributions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Gauss' law in reverse.  Imagine some material with permittivity $\epsilon$ and some spherically symmetric volume charge density $\rho(r)$.  Take a Gaussian sphere of radius $R$ so that
\begin{align}
\oint_S \vec E\cdot d\vec S&= \vert \vec E\vert \times 4\pi R^2=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\oint_V\rho(r) dV\, ,\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{\epsilon} \int_0^R\,dr r^2\rho(r)\, .
\end{align}
As you want the field to go $\sim 1/R$ for the potential to be in $\log$, choosing $\rho(R)=\rho_0/r^2$ gives
$$
\vert \vec E\vert r^2=\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon} r
$$
which implies 
$$
\vec E=\frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon r}\hat r
$$
which in turn implies that, inside this material, the potential will go like $\log(r)$.

Note that, as pointed out by @ArmandoEstebanQuito, this would be a charge distribution singular at the origin.  Also note that, if you wish to remove that singularity by having a hollow material so that $r=0$ is excluded, then 
$$
\int_0^{R} dr\,r^2\rho(r)\to \int_{R_0}^R dr\,r^2\rho(r) =
\int_{R_0}^R dr = R-R_0 
$$
so that now
$$
\vert \vec E\vert = \frac{\rho_0}{\epsilon r^2}(r-R_0)
$$
will contain a logarithmic part but also a $1/r$ part.

Comment: @ArmandoEstebanQuito Oh dear!  I just realized I repeated your comment, which I did not see because some comments were hidden for length of list.